# Marketing Cloud: Personalized Strings from salesforce lead

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are using Salesforce Leads to trigger Journeys in Marketing cloud. Whenever the field value is changed we need to send an email containing the value of this field to this Lead. The field value is a URL and it should be added as a href to a link within a template. We already able to send those emails with help of a Journey Builder and Entry Event as Salesforce Data. The only thing I am missing is how to use Personalization Strings to populate Event Data from this screenshot http://take.ms/FYsqy to actual email we send.

Thank you!

Comment: Great news! You could post your own solution as answer to your question and accept it instead of an edit, so other users can easily see that there is a working solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion from Markus Slabina posting answer separately from the original post.

Proposed by community solution didn't work. But I was able to manage this with help of RetrieveSalesforceObjects function:

```
%%[ 
var @LeadTable, @LeadRow, @HomeEval 
set @LeadTable = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead','Home_Evaluation_URL__c, Safe_Id__c','Safe_Id__c', '=', _subscriberkey) 
set @LeadRow = ROW(@LeadTable, 1) 
set @HomeEval = FIELD(@LeadRow, 'Home_Evaluation_URL__c')
]%%
```

Home Evaluation
Hope this will help someone that may face the same need/issue as I did.